# Php Undefined index writing xml file

Tags: xml, php

Im writing an xml using php from html form and i cant move on because of this problem.. thank you for helping!!

```
 <?php 
  $root = array();  
 $root [] = array( 
 'subtitle' => $_POST['subtitle'], 
 ); 
 echo $_POST['subtitle'];//checker if POST really passes data

 $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
 $doc->formatOutput = true; 

 $r = $doc->createElement( "root" ); 
 $doc->appendChild( $r ); 

 $subtitle = $doc->createElement( "subtitle" ); 
 $subtitle->appendChild($doc->createTextNode( $root['subtitle'])); --Undefined index-
 $r->appendChild( $subtitle );
```

$root['subtitle'] is undefined and i dont know why.

```
 echo $doc->saveXML(); 
 $doc->save(.$_POST['title'].".xml") 
 ?>
```

the code does generate an xml file but the nodes are empty

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <subtitle></subtitle>
</root>
```

THANKS!

wrote print_r($root) and wrote qwerty in the form. this is the output
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [subtitle] => qwerty ) )

Comment: Can you copy the error message to us please?

Comment: Try doing a print_r($root) to see what is contained within the array.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: subtitle in ...\testcode.php @ChrisCooney

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `$root [] = array(...)`. So it creates another array at index **0** of the `$root` array.

Try doing :

```
$subtitle->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($root[0]['subtitle']));
```

Or remove the brackets when initializing the `$root` array.

Comment: Or just remove the [] from the `$root = array(...)` declaration :)

Comment: Yes, I was just adding that to my answer ;)

Comment: perfect! i was stuck with this problem for hours even tried reconstructing my xml template. lol. freaking brackets. THANKS!